# Handling NULL values while calculating average

Tags: stored-procedures, null, sql-server-2008-r2, average

I have a stored procedure which calculates the average of several values upon the parameters.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN               
    SELECT 
       @valFound = AVG(FilterSurface) 
    FROM 
       [tblVAR_FilterSurface] 
    WHERE 
       refDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, @refDate) 
       AND refDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 0, @refDate) 
       AND patientId = @patientId

    INSERT INTO __TEMP(PatientId, RefDate, ModifyDate, FilterSurface) 
    VALUES(@patientId, @refDate, @modifyDate, @valFound);   

    SET @valFound = NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @patientId, @refDate, @modifyDate   
END
```

Sometimes this stored procedure fails as the system try to calculate the average of NULL values and assign the result to `@valFound` variable. I think the problem is the assignment of result to that variables.

How can I modify my stored procedure in order to handle correctly null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the select to @valFound = avg(isnull(FilterSurface, 0)) or change your where clause to include and FilterSurface is not null, depending if you want to count nulls as zero or exclude them